# iOS TextView get crash after UIView animation completion block

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, textview, completion

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [viewMain setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 1024, 378)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [txtViewNote becomeFirstResponder]; //Its a TextView
        }];
```

The above code works fine most of the time. But sometimes the line

```
[txtNote becomeFirstResponder]
```

cause crash. I have try-catch. But crash does not go to catch block.

Comment: Make sure you are calling the animation from the main thread.

Comment: I am calling from main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fix the issue.
Its actually happens when I come to this view 2nd time. 
I have 2 observer for keyboard

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

But I did not remove observer while closing the view. Thats why when come to this view for 2nd time the core code couldn't handle it. Don't know what actually problem it is in cocoa-touch. But its solved.